# Azure Service Fabric cluster to run windows containers on windows 7 single machine

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-service-fabric, azure-service-fabric-mesh

I want to use Service Fabric to run windows containers on my windows 7 machine. Docker is not installed on my machine. It seems windows 7 cannot run docker as it does not have  Hyper-V. We have created docker images separately and pushed it to a containers registry.

I created a new service fabric project on my machine using Visual Studio 2017 and selected Container as an option. Project template is giving me a warning :

```
The local machine cannot run guest containers because the operating system does not support 'Container' feature.
```

**My question is** even though I do not have Docker installed on my local machine, can I still run service fabric cluster which host containers? I have installed Service Fabric SDK on my machine.

Comment: Are you attempting to run Linux Containers or Windows Containers?

Comment: @Micah_MSFT: windows containers

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 is technically supported for developing Service Fabric

[Service Fabric Supported Operating Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#supported-operating-system-versions)

[image]

As you see, there is an extra step if you are using Windows 7 but it is still supported.

However, since you want to run Windows Containers in Service Fabric, this requires you to install [Docker CE for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows?tab=description) which is designed for Windows 10 and requires Hyper-V to be enabled.

So long answer short, you won't be able to do it while running Windows 7